Reverse proxy HTTPS to HTTP switch causes signin issue witn MS Login in .NET
I have an application which I like to publish over a reverse proxy (in my case Traefik). So my calls look like this:

Browser --> HTTPS --> k8s-ingress/Traefik --http --> App Container

I found this one:
Reply address does not match the reply address provided when requesting authorization
I already did the following changes to my code to fix it:

Add UseForwardedHeaders-Middleware
var forwardedHeadersOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
 {
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost,
 };
app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardedHeadersOptions);


Told my Traefik to send the headers
customRequestHeaders:
  X-Forwarded-Host: instance.mydomain.com
  X-Forwarded-Proto: https

Now the forward from the App will be created wrong even if the headers are included. (Checked that by logging the headers for each request). The generated redirect_uri is:
http://instance.mydomain.com/authpath


Go for manually setting the redirect path
.AddMicrosoftAccount(AuthenticationSchemas.Microsoft, m =>
{
  m.Events = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthEvents()
  {
    OnRedirectToAuthorizationEndpoint = async ctx =>
    {
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(ctx.RedirectUri);
        var queryParams = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uriBuilder.Query);

        var backRedirect = queryParams["redirect_uri"];
        if (backRedirect == null || backRedirect.StartsWith("http://localhost"))
         return;

        var redirectUri = new UriBuilder(backRedirect);
        redirectUri.Port = -1;
        redirectUri.Scheme = "https";
        queryParams["redirect_uri"] = redirectUri.ToString();

        uriBuilder.Query = queryParams.ToString();
        ctx.RedirectUri = uriBuilder.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(ctx.RedirectUri);
        ctx.Response.Redirect(ctx.RedirectUri);
    },
  }
}

Now I get an Exception:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: 
  OAuth token endpoint failure: 
    invalid_client;Description=AADSTS500112: 
      The reply address 'http://instance.mydomain.com/authpath' does not match the reply address 'https://instance.mydomain.com/authpath' provided when requesting Authorization code.



It seems that the value, which is determined by the middleware is saved somewhere. So it finds that I redirected to https, but get called by http.
Can I disable this check somehow? Is there any other way to get this working?

Setting up the forward headers middleware like this did the trick:
var forwardedHeadersOptions = new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor 
      | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto 
      | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedHost,
    RequireHeaderSymmetry = false
};
forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownNetworks.Clear();
forwardedHeadersOptions.KnownProxies.Clear();
app.UseForwardedHeaders(forwardedHeadersOptions);

